# How can I plot two different variables in the same figure and distinguish them in the legend?

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, aes, geom

I want to draw two variables in a same figure, and for some details I want to distinguish them by the legend.

Please see the original data below:

```
df<-structure(list(Bloc = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 
                             7, 8, 8, 5, 5), Pos_heliaphen = c("W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", 
                                                               "X02", "X03", "W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03", "W16", 
                                                               "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03"), traitement = c("WS", "WW", 
                                                                                                                  "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", 
                                                                                                                  "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW"), Variete = c("Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                             "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                             "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                             "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas"), Date_obs = c("D07_27/05/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D07_27/05/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D13_08/06/2021"), P_av_arros = c(0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.07, 1.08), FTSW_apres_arros = c(-0.82561716279966, -0.83052784248231, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -0.833812425397989, -0.826677385087996, -0.831991201718322, -0.827650244364889, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.900083501645054, 0.899646933005172, 0.920126486265779, 0.901668054319428, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.899616920453791, 0.899570142896103, -0.82561716279966, -0.83052784248231, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -0.833812425397989, -0.826677385087996, -0.831991201718322, -0.827650244364889
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -18L))
```

I've already tried with the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

labels <- df %>% 
  select(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) %>% 
  distinct(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) %>% 
  group_by(Bloc) %>% 
  summarise(Pos_heliaphen = paste(Pos_heliaphen, collapse = "-")) %>% 
  tibble::deframe()

df %>%
  select(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, FTSW_apres_arros, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, linetype = traitement, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

And I gained the figure below:
[image]

I can also the figure below if I change `FTSW_apres_arros` to `P_av_arros`:
[image]

Now I want to put the two variables `FTSW_apres_arros` and `P_av_arros`in the same figure.
Below is the legend that I hope I can have:

[image]

I'm not sure if I explain my question clearly. Thanks in advance if anyone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to reshape your data to long before passing it to `ggplot`. This way you get a new `Variables` and a `value` column. The `Variables` column could be mapped on `linetype` while the `value` column is mapped on `y`. Additionally you have to add `Variables` to the `interaction` mapped on `group`. .

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(P_av_arros, FTSW_apres_arros), names_to = "Variables") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, 
             linetype = Variables, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement, Variables))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Unfortunately there is AFAIK no easy way to put legends in multiple rows and columns at the same time, i.e. using `theme(legend.box.just = ...)` you could have them all in one row (`= "horizontal"`) or in one column (`= "vertical"`).

One possible option would be to use `cowplot::get_legend` to extract the legends from your plot and then use `patchwork` to get closer to your desired result. However, when doing so the single legends will be centered and I'm afraid aligning them nicely requires a lot of effort.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

p <- df %>%
  select(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(P_av_arros, FTSW_apres_arros), names_to = "Variables") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, 
             linetype = Variables, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement, Variables))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

legends <- get_legend(p)

p1 <- p + guides(color = "none", linetype = "none", shape = "none")

design <- "
AB
#C
"
p1 / (wrap_plots(legends$grobs[1:3], design = design)) + plot_layout(heights = c(10, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe do you know how to adjust the legend of `traitement` to be **just** below the `Variables`? But anyway, thank you for helping me again!!! @stefan

Comment: Hi Chouette. Unfortunately there is no easy option. But see my edit. Maybe this helps.